Asphalt 9 closing as soon as it opens in waydroid
I have done the permission changes according to https://github.com/waydroid/waydroid/issues/702
installed Waydroid_scripts
but then also it's not working

You've not yet told us what Ubuntu product, and release of that unstated Ubuntu product you're using.  Did you explore logs on your unstated system for clues?  (or if started from terminal; any clues in the messages/output?)

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.
